# Help with subsets/subgroups question

Tags: group-theory

Let $S\subseteq G$. Let $K = \bigcap\{H: H \le G\text{ and }S \subseteq H\}$, the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ that contain $S$

Lemma: $\langle S\rangle = K$

Prove that $\langle S\rangle\subseteq K$ and $K\subseteq\langle S\rangle$:

"$S\subseteq\langle S\rangle\le G \implies K \subseteq \langle S\rangle$

Let $x\in\langle S\rangle$. Let $H \le G$ and $S\subseteq H$.

Then $\langle S\rangle\le H \implies x\in H \implies x \in \bigcap H$

$\implies x \in K \implies\langle S\rangle\subseteq K$

Thus $\langle S\rangle = K$"

I don't really understand this proof, largely two steps:

1. "$S\subseteq\langle S\rangle\le G \implies K \subseteq\langle S\rangle$" (I'm not sure how this implies $K\subseteq\langle S\rangle$)
2. How is "$x\in H \implies x \in \bigcap H$" implied?

Could someone please elaborate? Any help appreciated

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

For item 1: suppose $s \in S$. Then is $s \in K$? Well, for any $H$ with $ H \le G$ and $S \subset H$ (i.e., any of the $H$s used to define $K$), we have $s \in H$. So $s$ is in the intersection of all such $H$. Hence $s \in K$.

Answer (score 1):

It will be convenient to let $\mathscr{H}=\{H\le G:S\subseteq H\}$, so that $K=\bigcap\mathscr{H}$.

For your first question, $\langle S\rangle$ is by definition a subgroup of $G$ that contains $S$, so $\langle S\rangle\in\mathscr{H}$. $K$ is the intersection of all such subgroups of $G$, so $K$ is a subset of every $H\in\mathscr{H}$. In particular, $K\subseteq\langle S\rangle$.

For your second question, let $x\in\langle S\rangle$. Let $H$ be any member of $\mathscr{H}$; then $x\in\langle S\rangle\le H$, so $x\in H$. This is true for **every** $H\in\mathscr{H}$, so by definition $x\in\bigcap\mathscr{H}$: that intersection is precisely the set of things that are in every member of $\mathscr{H}$. Thus, $x\in K$, and therefore $\langle S\rangle\subseteq K$.